# Odd short duration duplication behavior in ng-repeat with angular-material buttons

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEMqVG?editors=101) is a code pen for the (stripped down) material version and [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrqqP?editors=101) is the (stripped down) bootstrap version.  Except for dependencies all of the javascript is the same.

I have a server side paging directive that uses bootstrap css (I'm not sure if the angular-bootstrap library didn't have pagination at the time or if I just hadn't found it yet).  I decided to port it over to angular-material, thinking the directive logic could be completely reused and I could just switch out the template.  With the angular-material version all of the md-buttons that form the pager are duplicated for a split second and then go away every time the pager is rebuilt.  I rebuild the pager after every ajax call because filters can change the total number of pages.  A stripped down version of the pager follows:

```
app.controller('pagerCtrl', [
            '$scope', 'userService', function ($scope, userService) {
                var self = this;

                self.pageNumber = 1;
                self.page = function (number) {
                    self.pageNumber = number;
                    self.refresh();
                }
                self.refresh = function () {
                    userService.loadAllUsers().then(function (users) {
                        self.users = [].concat(users.data);
                        self.paging = users.paging;
                        self.buildPager();
                    });
                }
                self.buildPager = function () {
                    var pages = [];
                    for (var i = 1; i < self.paging.numberOfPages + 1; i++) {
                        pages.push({ number: i, isActive: self.pageNumber === i });
                    }
                    self.pages = [].concat(pages);
                }
                self.refresh();
            }]);
```

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEMqVG?editors=101) is a code pen for the (stripped down) material version and [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrqqP?editors=101) is the (stripped down) bootstrap version.  Except for dependencies all of the javascript is the same.

I'm wondering if this is expected behavior and if there is anything I can do to make the momentary duplication stop.  I've played around with several variations of nulling out pages before setting it, setting the pages to [].concat(pages) as they do in the demo project.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any css animations in your stylesheets?

Comment: In just using the default material-design css at the moment.  I think the 'ink' effect is on by default, I'll try removing that and see if it helps.

Comment: I threw an md-no-ink onto the buttons and they still do the same thing.  Good call though.

Comment: this behavior is not occurring in v0.8.3-master-74601d0 from rawgit, did occur in v0.8.3 from bower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling animations fixes the issue (although it might break other stuff).

Take a look at [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbqPxP).

I disabled animations globally and the problem disappears.

```
app.run(function($animate){
    $animate.enabled(false);
})
```

You can locally disable animations for elements as well.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the animate api, but I imagine I could inject it into the controller and disable it on each button.  Is that correct?